# Does Cython have something like std::unique_ptr?

Tags: python, cython, unique-ptr

Does Cython have a way to wrap malloc'd values so they get GC'd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCapsule is sort of ugly because you have to define a destructor for each class, but it does the trick:

```
from cpython cimport pycapsule

cdef const char* CAPNAME = "ExtClassName" 
cdef void del_capsule(object o):
  cdef ExtClass* cobject = <ExtClass*>pycapsule.PyCapsule_GetPointer(o, CAPNAME)
  del cobject

def mk_cpp_object():
  return pycapsule.PyCapsule_New(cp, CAPNAME, del_capsule)
```

There's probably a way to do this 'more automatically' by defining in C++ a template that manufactures its own destructor. Then that type could be instantiated in cython.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with this:

```
cdef class AutoPtr:
    cdef void* _ptr
    def __cinit__(self): self._ptr = NULL
    def __dealloc__(self):
        if self._ptr: mem.PyMem_Free(self._ptr) # or whatever free function is relevant to your codebase
        self._ptr = NULL

cdef AutoPtr mkauto(void* ptr):
    cdef AutoPtr wrapper = AutoPtr()
    wrapper._ptr = ptr
    return wrapper
```

I think that `__cinit__` forces its arguments to python objects, so something like this won't even compile:

```
cdef class AutoPtr:
    cdef void* _ptr
    def __cinit__(self, void* ptr): self._ptr = ptr
    def __dealloc__(self): pass # etc
```

Here's a forum post to that effect: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cython-devel/2012-June/002734.html

Given what Cython is, I'm assuming there's a built-in deallocating wrapper that I just don't know about.